# addEventListener on window doesn't recognize event? load/DOMContentLoaded not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, addeventlistener, window.open, domcontentloaded

I am trying to open a new window when a button is clicked and print something in the new window.
I've linked the button to the following 'switchToNewWindow' method:

```
windowOpen: false,

switchToNewWindow() {
  if (!this.windowOpen) {
    var win = window.open('', '_blank', 'location=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,top=200,left=350,width=1200,height=650');
    this.windowOpen = true;
    win.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
      this.windowOpen = false;
    }.bind(this));
  }
},
```

The method as it is above, it's working, but if I want to change the listener as follows below, the code from the listener doesn't execute.

```
win.addEventListener('load', function () {
    win.document.write("Hello, world!");
});
```

In the console while debugging I can see that the code doesn't enter the function in the second example.
I should mention I tried also with 'DOMContentLoaded' instead of 'load', and still not working.
My guess is that the event is not recognized? Any idea on why or what else is broken here? And why it is working with 'beforeunload'?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `bind()` call in the last code snippet? You never use `this` in the function body.

Comment: no purpose, sorry. just a copy paste mistake. will edit the post.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for using `window.open` and not creating a sencha window `Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {.....})`?

Comment: I second @dev, I think it is much easier to create an ExtJS window within your application than opening a new browser window and communicate with it.

Comment: @dev I've tried with the sencha Window as well, but I want to be able to move the window from one screen to the other, and this is possible with the window.open but I couldn't add this behaviour to the sencha window. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I think you can't do this with sencha window. Check my answer and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using a custom event. Maybe not the best approach but check if it works for your case.

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script>
    function switchToNewWindow() {
        var win = window.open('', '_blank', 'location=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,top=200,left=350,width=1200,height=650');
      
        win.addEventListener('writetowin', function(){
            this.document.write('Hello World');
        });

        var myEvent = new CustomEvent('writetowin');

        win.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="click" onclick="switchToNewWindow()"/>
</body>
</html>
```